# How to understand the dimensionality of 3D MRI or Nifti images?

Tags: image-processing, bioinformatics, medical-imaging

I see that 3D images in the shape of X*Y*Z, where X is the height of the image, Y the breadth, and Z the depth. Depth indicates the number of 2D images that make this single 3D MRI images. Right?

Is my understanding correct or is there something that I need to more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct with the general idea about image shapes.

One important consideration is that different software packages index images different. For example in Python, images stored as `numpy.ndarray` objects are indexed as `[z,y,x]` but in `SimpleITK.Image` format they are indexed as `[x,y,z]`.

There are also higher-dimensional images, for example 4D-CT scans (with time being the fourth dimension), and vector images like diffusion MRI.